# Packaging SF service into a single file

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am working through how to automate the build and deploy of my Service Fabric app. Currently I'm working on the package step and while it is creating files within the pkg subfolder it is always creating a folder hierarchy of files, not a true package in a single file. I would swear I've seem a .SFPKG file (or something similarly named) that has everything in one file (a zip maybe?). Is there some way to to create such a file with msbuild?

Here's the command line I'm using currently:

```
msbuild myservice.sfproj "/p:Configuration=Dev;Platform=AnyCPU" /t:Package /consoleloggerparameters:verbosity=minimal /maxcpucount
```

I'm concerned about not having a single file because it seems inefficient in sending a new package up to my clusters, and it's harder for me to manage a bunch of files on a build automation server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you read about the .sfpkg at
https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster

Note that internally we do not yet support provisioning a .sfpkg file. This is a feature that will be coming in soon (date TBD). Instead, we upload each file in the application package.

## Update (SF 6.1 - April 2018)

Since 6.1 it is possible to create a ZIP file (`*.sfpkg`) and upload it to an external store. Service Fabric executes a GET operation to download the `sfpkg application package`. For more infos see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-package-apps#create-an-sfpkg

NOTE: This only works with external provisioning, the Azure image store still doesn't support `sfpkg` files.

Comment: Is it supported now ?

Comment: No. We have added support for uploading compressed packages (coming in next release), but the compressed package is still a folder that contains manifests and compressed code/package/config. This will be described in the documentation for the new feature. We provide utilities to compress/uncompress the package, so its shape is not essential to use the feature. Can you explain why is it harder for you to deal with a folder? Note that we still have tracking items to provide one .sfpkg file plus another file for application parameters, but we have no ETA.

Comment: I guess it's easier to deal with a single file rather than a folder. Less files = less room for mistakes and tampering.

Comment: I see, thank you for follow up. I will update the thread when I have more details.